# Car wheels not rotating properly, how to fix?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation

I have a very basic car model. So far I have managed to get the wheels rotating in one of two ways:

- The wheel rotates on the local Z axis when it turns
- The wheel rotates on the local Y axis when it drives forward or backward

They both work fine, but I just cannot get them both to work at the same time. I am absolutely stumped and its starting to piss me off! I have also been trying to follow this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0jvJ2FMvbBs) and have the following error:

- Cannot modify a value type return of 'UnityEngine.Transform.rotation'. Consider storing the value in a temporary variable.

Could someone take a look at my code and show me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Code:

```
public Wheels[] wheel;
public float enginePower = 20f;
public float turnPower = 20f;

void FixedUpdate () {
    float torque = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * enginePower;
    float turnSpeed = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * turnPower;

    //4 Wheel Drive
    wheel[0].Move(torque);
    wheel[1].Move(torque);
    wheel[2].Move(torque);
    wheel[3].Move(torque);

    //Front Wheel Steering
    wheel[0].Turn(turnSpeed);
    wheel[1].Turn(turnSpeed);
}

void Update () {
    wheel[0].transform.Rotate(0, 0, wheel[0].GetComponent<WheelCollider>().rpm / 60 * 360 * Time.deltaTime);

    //Only one wheel is shown for simplicity

    wheel[0].transform.rotation.y = wheel[0].GetComponent<WheelCollider>().steerAngle - wheel[0].transform.rotation.z;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The "rotation" variable of a Transform is a `Quaternion` thus what you are trying to do in your second line of your code in Update will break the rotation. Instead, you'll have to use `transform.Rotate` again and access the z value of the rotation from the transform's local euler angles.

```
wheel[0].transform.Rotate(0, wheel[0].GetComponent<WheelCollider>().steerAngle - wheel[0].transform.localEulerAngles.z, 0);
```